# SecTrustCreateWithCertificates crashes on iPad

Tags: iphone, security, ipad, certificate, public-key

I am trying to use iOS security framework to securely communicate with my server. I have a certificate file from which I am able to get a public key reference. This is what I doing.

```
 NSString *certPath    = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"supportwarriors.com" ofType:@"cer"];
 SecCertificateRef myCertificate = nil;

 NSData *certificateData   = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:certPath]; 
 myCertificate     = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFDataRef)certificateData);

 //got certificate ref..Now get public key secKeyRef reference from certificate..
 SecPolicyRef myPolicy   = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
 SecTrustRef myTrust;
 OSStatus status     = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(myCertificate,myPolicy,&myTrust);  

    SecTrustResultType trustResult;
    if (status == noErr) {
        status = SecTrustEvaluate(myTrust, &trustResult);  
    }
 publicKey      = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(myTrust);
```

Above piece of code works perfectly on iPhone and I have tested that. I am able to securely communicate with my server. But when I try to run my app on iPad (in 2x mode) the above code getting crashed. After debug, I found out that secTrustCreateWithCertificate is crashing and the crash log is given below.. Certificate I used is same for both iPad and iPhone...The function above secCertificateCreateWithData returning a certificate reference and is not nil...So that is not the cause of crash..What am  I doing wrong.

```
*** -[NSCFType count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14af24
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***      -[NSCFType count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14af24'
```

Comment: Can you post the certificate?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for `SecTrustCreateWithCertificates` claims that you can pass either a single certificate OR an array.  The exception you're receiving states that `-[NSCFType count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.  What's happening in iOS 3.2 is that `SecTrustCreateWithCertificates` is treating the input value like a CFArray without checking first to see if it's a singular `SecCertificateRef`.

To get around this, you can do something similar to the following code:

```
    SecCertificateRef certs[1] = { certificate };
    CFArrayRef array = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (const void **) certs, 1, NULL);
    if(SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(array, x509Policy, &trustChain) == errSecSuccess)
```

just remember to `CFRelease(array)` at the appropriate scope.